# I need simple proxy between 2 rest APIs

Tags: rest, proxy

My code is working ok for GET/POST/PUT to/from restApi1 and restApi2.
However, my problem I need to implement HEAD/OPTIONS (no body!) and GET uri1
HEAD/OPTIONS could return 204 or 200 depends on a process status. I am getting error "Stream closed". Sounds like Camel want body bytes, but I don't indend to have it. Even I set ExchangePattern.InOnly or optional etc error occur...
What is correct way to see responses and handle requests WITHOUT body, just statuses exchange?
How to see response from restApi2 on Camel rest("/restApi1").head().route().routeId("id1")
.to("direct:restApi2").routeId("/id1").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,constant("HEAD"))
setExchanggePattern(ExchangePattern.OutOptionalIn).recepientList(simple(restApi2));

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Need to set '.convertBodyTo(String.class)' even I don't have a body.